# Is there a way to get the point information inside formatter function of y aixs label?

Tags: highcharts, gantt-chart

I am rendering a highcharts gantt and want to modify the y axis labels

in the formatter function of the label i get point is undefined and want to know how to get that information

```
yAxis: {
    useHTML: true,
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            console.log(this);
            return `
            <a class="left">
                <strong> ${this.value} </strong> 
                <br/> 
                <i>Job Type</i>
            </a>`;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no real direct link between the axis labels and any point. You could be lucky and there's a point in at least one series at that exact value, but you could also have a complete miss. You could just loop through the series and find something that is close to your labels position, which would just be going this `this.chart.series` in your formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `formatter` function is called multiple times and points do not exist in the first call. However, you can get points by `this.chart.series[X].points` in the later calls and compare `this.pos` with `point.y`:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
            var seriesPoints = this.chart.series[0].points,
                points,
                result = '<a class="left"><strong>',
                pos = this.pos;

            if (seriesPoints) {
                points = seriesPoints.filter(function(p) {
                    return p.y === pos;
                });

                points.forEach(function(p) {
                    result += p.name + '<br/>'
                });

                result += '</strong><i>Job Type</i></a>'

                return result
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sa0ykrpn/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/yAxis.labels.formatter